# esri maps Popup location is shifted when scrolling

Tags: javascript, gis, esri

[image]

When I scroll the screen and click on a pin on the map the popup is shifted from location
I am using javascript with PopupTemplate

```
var g = new Graphic({
                        geometry: point,
                        symbol: picSym,
                        popupTemplate: new PopupTemplate({
                            title: getDealerPopupTitleSP(data[dealerPMA]),
                            content: getDealerPopupContentSP(data[dealerPMA],dealer1,dealer2,dealer3)
                        })
                    });
```